# Delete multiple elements by properties from array by list of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have a problem that I cannot solve and it seems a little strange to me. Having a list of objects `foo`, each object having a `userId` property, I want to filter the list to remove all items containing such `userId` that are in the `bar` array.
I used the `filter()` and `some()` methods, however, they only work when the `bar` array has only one element.
Does `some()` somehow stop the entire filter from running when it finds the first matching element?
I would be thankful if you could explain to me why this does not work.

Example code:

```js
let foo = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
  },
  {
    "userId": 2
  },
  {
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "userId": 4
  }
];

let bar = [1, 2];

console.log(foo.filter(user => bar.some(id => id !== user.userId)));
```

Expected value:

```json
[
  {
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "userId": 4
  }
]
```

But I got:

```js
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
  },
  {
    "userId": 2
  },
  {
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "userId": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: _"The [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method executes the `callbackFn` function once for each element present in the array **until it finds the one where `callbackFn` returns a truthy value** (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, `some()` **immediately returns true**. Otherwise, `some()` returns `false`."_

Comment: Use `.includes()` instead of `.some()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition currently checks if there is **at least one item in the bar array which is not the same as the items array you are iterating over**. That will be true for all items.

You need to check for the items that **exist** using `some()` and based on that return the inverse value .

```js
let foo = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
  },
  {
    "userId": 2
  },
  {
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "userId": 4
  }
];

let bar = [1, 2];

console.log(foo.filter(user => !bar.some(id => id === user.userId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `includes` methods to check this situation.

```js
let foo = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
  },
  {
    "userId": 2
  },
  {
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "userId": 4
  }
];

let bar = [1, 2];
// filter out for user IDs not in bar
console.log(foo.filter(user => !bar.includes(user.userId)));
```

for more information about includes method: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test.

Explanation of Why `some()` is not working here:

`[1,2].some(id !== 1)` will return `true` because id `2 !== 1`

`[1,2].some(id !== 2)` will return `true` because id `1 !== 2`

`[1,2].some(id !== 3)` will return `true` because id `1 !== 3`

`[1,2].some(id !== 4)` will return `true` because id `1 !== 4`